# How to effectively know what's wrong with input via Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, validation, jsoup

I am trying to validate HTML code using Jsoup and the method `Jsoup.isValid` always returns false but I'm in the dark here because it does not tell me where the error is.

Here is my code:

```
class PageWhitelist extends Whitelist {
    public PageWhitelist() {
        addTags("html", "head", "meta", "style", "body", "a", "div");
        addProtocols("a", "href", "http");
    }
}

String markup = "<body><head>...";

PageWhitelist whitelist = new PageWhitelist();
boolean valid = Jsoup.isValid(markup, whitelist);
assertTrue(valid);
```

`valid` simply evaluates to false, the test fails and Jsoup does not give me any clue of what is causing the error whatsoever.

How can I know what is really going on?

Comment: Is that class definition even valid? AdMarkupWhitelist looks like a constructor (no return type) but it's not named the same as the class name...

Comment: sorry, now you know the real name of my class :p but that is not the problem

Comment: unfortunately, seems there is no straightforward way to do this. Look at https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.java#L60 which used by `Jsoup.isValid` internally. I think the only way is calculate a difference between dirty and cleaned document.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago and got an answer. [JSOUP - How to get list of disallowed tags found in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817745/jsoup-how-to-get-list-of-disallowed-tags-found-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've never used `isValid` cause HTML validation is something that depends on what you really want to see in the page. For example, let's say you requested a page and selected an element. This element being NULL means that the HTML is invalid for me.

What I do is: let's say that I want a anchor like

`a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509726/how-to-effectively-know-whats-wrong-with-input-via-jsoup`

I use the Jsoup to select the element. If it comes `NULL` means that my page is invalid.

```
Elements anchors = Jsoup.parse(html).select("a[href*=stackoverflow.com/questions/]");
if (anchors.isEmpty()) {
  // Invalid
}
// valid
```